# Margin between columns

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

As Bootstrap 5 use paddings in columns, I have some problems with some of my columns having a background, or for example when I need to add an embed element. How can I do to have some margins ?

[image]

To realize that, I had to do a trick by giving different classes to my 3 grey blocks and add to each one left margin/right margin as each one required.

I wanted to do something like that :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            My blue section
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            Grey section 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            Grey section 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            Grey section 3
        </div>
    </div>
```

But unfortunately I cannot because I will have no margins between my grey items. So I tried to encapsulate like this each grey item :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="item">
                Grey section 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="item">
                Grey section 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="item">
                Grey section 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But this isn't good too because I will have margins from the row on left and right and the total width will be different between the grey section and the blue section.

I had the same problem for videos : I had to embed but if I don't encapsulate my video in a child div, I have no margins and it's a problem.

What could I do for that ?

Comment: Your problem isn't clear. What do you want to achieve? What is the desired result?

Comment: I thought it was clear. I want to obtain 3 columns, with a coloured background in it and spacing between them, without having margin on left and right of the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are talking about the spacing between the column items.

Since Bootstrap columns are managed via CSS flexbox since version 4, you can easily achive your goal by also using [flexbox utilities](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

In this case you only need to set the `gap` (or `column-gap`) property for your second `row` element. And instead of fixed column size classes (`col-x`) use auto sized `col` class.

```css
.my-gap-row {
    gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        My blue section
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row my-gap-row">
    <div class="col">
        Grey section 1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        Grey section 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        Grey section 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't knew the gap property ! We're going outside of bootstrap but this is working nice ! I just don't know why there is no way to do that only with bootstrap Having elements with background in columns is a normal need. I tried previous comment but no one worked because I always have paddings around the row.

Answer (score 0):

Since you added the `css` tag, here's a `css` alternative solution. There's a property called `gap` if you use `flexbox`, `grid`, and multiple columns to easily add, as straightforward as the property name is, gaps in-between containers. See the snippet below as I reproduced your layout. More on `gap` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_gap.asp).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #2B2954;
  gap: .5rem;
}

.blue {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #18161B;
  grid-column: span 3;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

div.box:nth-child(2) {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #393D41;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

div.box:nth-child(3) {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #393D41;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

div.box:nth-child(4) {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #393D41;
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second try was good way to make margins between columns, but you have to apply some changes: change `row` to `d-flex justify-content-between` and `col-4` to for example `col-3`. It will make whitespace between column and whole element will close in 100% width of parent element.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="item">
                Grey section 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="item">
                Grey section 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="item">
                Grey section 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To add row gap, just add any `mt` to main `div`

Comment: This isn't working because that gives me very big space between my columns, and I also have paddings/margins on left and right of the row :/